# How to give start,end coordinates

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, a-star

I'm new to qgis and in here I want to find a path between two selected points on the map(Roads-vector layer). The points are selected by the user, using mouse clicks.
So here I used the astar algorithm to find path between two points.

*********************************astar.py************************************

```
import heapq

class AStar(object):  
    def __init__(self, graphAstar):  
        self.graphAstar = graphAstar

    def heuristic(self, node, start, end):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def search(self, start, end):
    openset = set()
        closedset = set()
        current = start
        openHeap = []
        openset.add(current)
        openHeap.append((0,current))
        while openset:
        temp = heapq.heappop(openHeap)
        current = temp[1]
            if current == end:
                path = []
                while current.parent:
                    path.append(current)
                    current = current.parent
                path.append(current)
                return path[::-1]
            openset.remove(current)
            closedset.add(current)
            for node in self.graphAstar[current]:
                if node in closedset:
                    continue
                if node in openset:
                    new_g = current.gg + current.move_cost(node)
                    if node.gg > new_g:
                        node.gg = new_g
                        node.parent = current
                else:
                    node.gg = current.gg + current.move_cost(node)
                    node.H = self.heuristic(node, start, end)
                    node.parent = current
                    openset.add(node)
            heapq.heappush(openHeap, (node.H,node))
        return None

    class AStarNode(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.gg = 0
            self.H = 0
            self.parent = None

        def move_cost(self, other):
            raise NotImplementedError

*****************************astar_grid.py*******************************

    from astar import AStar, AStarNode
    from math import sqrt

    class AStarGrid(AStar):
        def heuristic(self, node, start, end):
            return sqrt((end.x - node.x)**2 + (end.y - node.y)**2)

    class AStarGridNode(AStarNode):
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x, self.y = x, y
            super(AStarGridNode, self).__init__()

        def move_cost(self, other):
            diagonal = abs(self.x - other.x) == 1 and abs(self.y - other.y) == 1
            return 14 if diagonal else 10
```

and in the main code, the following method is used to create graph from vector layer.

****************************plugin.py************************************

```
def make_graph(self, mapinfo):
    nodes = [[AStarGridNode(x, y) for y in range(mapinfo['height'])] for x in range(mapinfo['width'])]
    graphAstar = {}
    for x, y in product(range(mapinfo['width']), range(mapinfo['height'])):
        node = nodes[x][y]
        graphAstar[node] = []
        for i, j in product([-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1]):
                if not (0 <= x + i < mapinfo['width']): continue
                if not (0 <= y + j < mapinfo['height']): continue
                graphAstar[nodes[x][y]].append(nodes[x+i][y+j])
    return graphAstar, nodes
```

And I called that method in FindRoutes method..

```
def findRoutes(self):
vl=self.canvas.currentLayer()
director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector( vl, -1, '', '', '', 3 )
properter = QgsDistanceArcProperter()
director.addProperter( properter )
crs = self.canvas.mapRenderer().destinationCrs()
builder = QgsGraphBuilder( crs )

global x1
global y1
global x2
global y2
pStart = QgsPoint( x1, y1 )
pStop = QgsPoint( x2, y2 )
graphAstar, nodes = self.make_graph({ "width": 8, "height": 8 })
paths = AStarGrid(graphAstar)

start, end = ??
path = paths.search(start, end)
```

My question is, how to pass the start and end coordinates to the function above? Because passing them just as coordinates (start, end = pStart, pStop) does not work.
How do add them to the graph created as nodes?
Or is there any easy way to do it?

Please help me to to find a solution to this problem.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

When i do an astar, the node i use are intern of the astar and contain a reference vers the original point object (your tuple of position).

Maybe it's the same with your `AStarGridNode` ?

In your case :

```
start = AStarGridNode(x1, y1)
stop = AStarGridNode(x2, y2)
```

This part could be in the your search function to hide this from the user.

Comment: So is there a way to capture that points. Because have to pass them in the search function. And is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You have your classic search call :

    path = paths.search(start, end)

With the start and end i defined previously. I notice that, there may be a problem with the equality relation into your search function (line `if current == end`. To resolve this, you could create a NonImplemented function into your AStarNode class and implement it into you AStarGraphNode : `return (x, y) == (other.x, other.y)`